# Textbox binding Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, events, textbox

I want to check if the input in a TextBox the format 00:00 matches. So I created a Method in my ViewModel:

```
private void MinPauseTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{
   //check text..
}
```

My binding in XAML looks like this:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="TextBoxSettingMinPause" TextChanged="{Binding Path=MinPauseTextChanged}" Text="{Binding Path=MinPauseSetting}"/>
```

I always get this error, but I don't know why, I followed the instruction on the Microsoft Site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textchangedeventargs?view=net-5.0

Here is my error-Code:
InvalidCastException: Object of type "System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo" cannot implicity connvert to "System.Reflection.MethodInfo".

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
Just add the StringFormat to your XAML Code, so it is like this:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="TextBoxSettingMinPause" Text="{Binding Path=MinPauseSetting, StringFormat={}{00:00}}" />
```

and delete the Method...